# How would I create a sub-procedure to sort numbers in ascending order? - VB console

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

It would be great if someone could help me out with my problem.

I need to create a VB console application that sorts 3 integer values into ascending order using a sub-procedure. The sub-procedure (e.g. called sortnumber()) needs to accept 3 integer parameters and then sort the values in ascending order.

How would I go about doing this, could someone point me in the right direction to a solution with code as simple as possible.

Thanks.

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim num1, num2, num3 As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number:")
    num1 = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter second number:")
    num2 = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter third number:")
    num3 = Console.ReadLine
sortnumber()
End Sub
Sub sortnumber(ByVal num1 As Integer, ByVal num2 As Integer, ByVal num3 As Integer)
    Dim
End Sub
```

I have no idea if this is right or where I am going with this..

Comment: So far I've put in all the main input/output code but now I am stuck with the sub-procedure. I don't want anyone to do it for me, just point me in the right direction.

EDIT: I also added the sortnumber() sub procedure using ByRef but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: You can read [at this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6xxtk8kx.aspx) how to create a function in VB.NET. Try something and add your code to your question.

Comment: Thanks but which function would sort the 3 numbers?

Comment: sorry i have not seen "console application" you cannot use my answer

Comment: @Kcode1 add your code to the question.

Comment: check my answer now it resloves your problem on console application

Comment: @pasty please look above.

Comment: @Kcode1 sorry but you have not asked the question clrealy now i know what are you trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Module Module1

Public Sub sortnumber(ByVal n1 As Integer, ByVal n2 As Integer, ByVal n3 As Integer)

    Dim l As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    l.Add(n1)
    l.Add(n2)
    l.Add(n3)
    l.Sort()
    For Each h In l
        Console.WriteLine(h.ToString)
    Next

End Sub
Sub Main()
    Dim num1, num2, num3 As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number:")
    num1 = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter second number:")
    num2 = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Enter third number:")
    num3 = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Calculating ......")
    sortnumber(num1, num2, num3)
    MsgBox("done")

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting an error with 'ListBox' as it says it is not defined. Also what does the 'p' in the code do?

Comment: @Kcode1 it sounds you dont know how to dispatch the code ok i will give you all the code

Comment: @Kcode1 now just copy and paste all the code or spearate it as above 
'function' must be in 'module' call must be in 'submain'

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I am looking for. I would like the user to input the numbers they would like so then the programme would then put them in order.

Comment: YES, this is pretty much what I was looking for. Just need to make a few changes and understand how it works. Thanks.
However, 1 number always only comes out as 0..so I do not know what went wrong there.

Comment: can you check as correct answer so ? and what do u want to make changes?

Comment: that is ok I have sorted it. Thanks once again. - works great

Answer (score 0):

When you are programming in VB.NET, it is possible to try to put the wrong sort of value into a variable. There are two places to guard against this: there could be such an error in your programming, and the user could enter the wrong information (e.g. entering "A" instead of a number).

VB in Visual Studio offers a way to detect the first of these problems: [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

In your program, you are trying to read a String (from ConsoleReadLine) into an Integer (e.g. num1). This is not really correct. Without Option Strict On, VB will try to make sense of what you have done, but sometimes it will guess the wrong thing about what you intended. If you use Option Strict On, it will notify you that something is awry. Fortunately, there are functions to convert from a String into an Integer (lots of other conversion are available).

For inputting a load of numbers, it might be nice if it was easy to adjust your program. Say you suddenly decided that you wanted to sort four numbers; you would then have to add another variable like num4 and re-write your sorting procedure. An Array is a useful type to use when you know in advance how many entries it will have because you can use one name to refer to it and a number to say which of the entries you want to use. A List is a sort of super-array as there are a lot of built-in operations which are useful.

Without addressing the problem of the user entering an invalid value, your program could look something like this:

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim nums As New List(Of Integer)

        Console.Write("Enter first number: ")
        nums.Add(Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
        Console.Write("Enter second number: ")
        nums.Add(Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))
        Console.Write("Enter third number: ")
        nums.Add(Integer.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))

        nums.Sort()

        Console.WriteLine("The sorted numbers are:")
        ' The index starts at 0, not 1.
        For i As Integer = 0 To nums.Count - 1
            Console.WriteLine(nums(i).ToString())
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```