# Have I done this Sub Procedures task correctly?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, console-application

The Programme

The programme will accept three integer values from a user and sort them into ascending order. The programme will also offer the opportunity to repeat the programme.

Instructions

- Create a sub-procedure called sortnumber() that accepts 3 integer parameters.
- Create the input/output code in main to read in 3 integer values to pass as arguments to sortnumber()
- Create the code in the sortnumber() to sort the 3 integer values in ascending order and print the result to the console
- Create the code that allows the user to repeat the programme

My code:

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim num1, num2, num3 As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("This programme sorts any 3 numbers into ascending order")
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue")
    Do Until Console.ReadLine = "e"
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your first number:")
        num1 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your second number:")
        num2 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your third number:")
        num3 = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("Sorting into ascending order...")
        sortnumber(num1, num2, num3)
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to repeat the programme or enter 'e' to exit")
    Loop

End Sub
Sub sortnumber(ByVal n1 As Integer, ByVal n2 As Integer, ByVal n3 As Integer)
    If n1 >= n2 And n2 >= n3 Then
        Console.WriteLine(n3)
        Console.WriteLine(n2)
        Console.WriteLine(n1)
    ElseIf n3 >= n2 And n2 >= n1 Then
        Console.WriteLine(n1)
        Console.WriteLine(n2)
        Console.WriteLine(n3)
    ElseIf n1 >= n3 And n3 >= n2 Then
        Console.WriteLine(n2)
        Console.WriteLine(n3)
        Console.WriteLine(n1)
    ElseIf n3 >= n1 And n1 >= n2 Then
        Console.WriteLine(n2)
        Console.WriteLine(n1)
        Console.WriteLine(n3)
    ElseIf n2 >= n3 And n3 >= n1 Then
        Console.WriteLine(n1)
        Console.WriteLine(n3)
        Console.WriteLine(n2)
    ElseIf n2 >= n1 And n1 >= n3 Then
        Console.WriteLine(n3)
        Console.WriteLine(n1)
        Console.WriteLine(n2) 
    End If
End Sub
End Module
```

Thanks.

Comment: your `sortnumber` procedure doesnt really sort anything, it just evaluates the values and prints accordingly. Step 3 is really 2 operations: a) sorting, b) output.  It depends on how literal the instructions are to be taken.

Comment: So according to the task set, have I done it correctly? @Plutonix

Comment: @Kcode1 i think that i have answered at this just yesterday ? if you want updates we continue there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018838/how-would-i-create-a-sub-procedure-to-sort-numbers-in-ascending-order-vb-cons/20019171#20019171

for deleting click on delet below the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what Plutonix had said, there is really no sorting that happens. But initially, yes you have shown the correct order of those three numbers in an ascending way.

I have tried to modify your sortnumber function so that it sorts them, but I used list a here.

```
Sub sortnumber(ByVal n1 As Integer, ByVal n2 As Integer, ByVal n3 As Integer)
    Dim numbers As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
    numbers.Add(n1)
    numbers.Add(n2)
    numbers.Add(n3)
    numbers.Sort()
    For Each num In numbers
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

By using the built-in `sort` function, the code can be read a lot cleaner.

But if it requires you to use conditions(i.e. if-else-if statements), then I would say that what you did is correct.

**Update:**

Assuming that you are doing this as an exercise, you can try using [Bubble Sort](http://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/vbnet-bubble-sort-algorithm/).

Comment: you have cloned my answer without anything changed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018838/how-would-i-create-a-sub-procedure-to-sort-numbers-in-ascending-order-vb-cons/20019171#20019171

Comment: @K3rnel31 Oh no I didnt. I manually tested this in my VS 2010. Please look at the code the OP have deleted/edited above. I just followed his format. - the function name, the parameters name ... I just included it in my new function  so that it will become easy for him. He shouldnt have deleted the answer though so you didnt misinterpret it.

Comment: yeah i see the name of function and the names of parameters and all !

Comment: @K3rnel31 Yeah that was exactly I am saying. A coincidence? Maybe :) but my naming convention is that function names must start in capital letter and parameters name to be not less than three letters except for demonstration purposes;)